# Can you charge a multi cell LiPo battery only using the balance lead socket?

Tags: battery-charging, remote-control

On a typical small LiPo battery charger like the one in the picture, can you charge a multi cell battery (like the one bellow) only using the *balance leads* **without** using the main/output *charge lead*?
[image: LiPo charger]

[image: lipo battery]

The reason I ask is because there are other smaller/simpler chargers that only have the balance lead connection like this:

[image: balance charger]

Comment: I suspect those connectors combine the balance leads with the main + and - leads. But no, the balance leads alone would only give you access to charge the middle cells in a pack.